# Choosing a grout color for a large brick patio

Tags: brick, grout

I am install a large brick patio, about 500 sq. ft.   We are planning to use a sand grout but want to get a sand color rather than a grey color.  Is this possible and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Outdoor brick patio's do **not use grout**, they use **polymeric sand** and typically it only comes two colors, grey and tan.

You could *do some research* to see if it is possible to dye it but not sure how it would hold up to the rain washing through it.